# Workaround implementation for "enum inheritance" in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

Preface: I've already researched why "*enum inheritance*" is illegal in Java.

My problem is the following: given a class `Recipe`, I want its property `category` to be a list of constant values like `APPETIZER, BREAKFAST, DESSERT, MAIN_COURSE, SOUP` - I logically use enums for this.

My question then is: if I wanted each of this enums to have "children of their own" (for example: `SWEET` and `SAVORY` for `BREAKFAST`, or `CAKE`, `MUFFIN` and `BISCUITS` for `DESSERT`), so that:

1. Specifying the subcategory ("child enum") is **mandatory** (e.g. `myRecipe.setCategory(DESSERT)` should raise an exception);
2. Using a "child enum" from a different "family" is **forbidden** (e.g. `SOUP.BISCUITS` should raise an exception);
3. I should be able to access the "child enum" through dot notation (e.g. `myRecipe.setCategory(DESSERT.CAKE)`) - or other similar "*lightweight*" syntax.

I haven't been able to come up with any *clean* solution in Java to fit all three requisites.

Is there any "esoteric" design pattern for this?
How would you implement this?

Comment: How would you store the categories persistently? Perhaps as a collection of categories that have an ID, name, and an optional parent ID. This would enforce the hierarchy. You could also disallow selecting a category where parent ID was null, which will implement your require subcategory selection.

Comment: Ideally, your code would not need to have the categories hard-coded into structures in the code. If you require that, I would create an interface for IRecipeCategory that implements the appropriate getters and setters for the category properties. Then, create classes for each category, with subcategories nested within their parent category classes. With every category / subcategory implementing the interface, your `.setCategory` method can accept any of them.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Design

Create a class *Category*. Inside Category, declare all the enum classes.

```
public class Category
{
    public enum APPETIZER
    {
    }

    public enum BREAKFAST
    {
        SWEET,
        SAVORY
    }

    public enum DESSERT
    {
        CAKE,
        MUFFIN,
        BISCUITS
    }

    public enum MAIN_COURSE
    {
    }
}
```

Inside the *Recipe* class, category should be of type `DESSERT`. I have static imported Category class.

```
public class Recipe
{
    DESSERT category;

    public void setCategory(DESSERT category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Recipe myRecipe = new Recipe();

        myRecipe.setCategory(DESSERT.BISCUITS);

        // statements below give compile time errors
        // myRecipe.setCategory(DESSERT);
        // myRecipe.setCategory(BREAKFAST.SWEET);
    }
}
```

---

### Improvement

Convert *Category* into a marker interface. All the categories such as `DESSERT`, `BREAKFAST`, etc. should implement Category.

```
interface Category {}

enum APPETIZER implements Category 
{
}

enum BREAKFAST implements Category
{
    SWEET,
    SAVORY
}

enum DESSERT implements Category
{
    CAKE,
    MUFFIN,
    BISCUITS
}

enum MAIN_COURSE implements Category
{
}
```

Make *Recipe* generic.

```
public class Recipe <T extends Category>
{
     T category;

    public void setCategory(T category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Recipe<DESSERT> myRecipe = new Recipe<>();

        myRecipe.setCategory(DESSERT.BISCUITS);

        // statements below give compile time errors
        // myRecipe.setCategory(DESSERT);
        // myRecipe.setCategory(BREAKFAST.SWEET);
    }
}
```

---

These are not design patterns. They are self implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
class Recipe {
    private final Meal meal;
    private final MealCategory category;

    public <T extends Meal> Recipe(T meal, MealCategory<T> category) {
        this.meal = meal;
        this.category = category;
    }
}
abstract class Meal {}
class Breakfast extends Meal {}
class Dinner extends Meal {}

class MealCategory<T extends Meal> {}

class Cereal extends MealCategory<Breakfast> {}
class Meat extends MealCategory<Dinner> {}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Recipe r = new Recipe(new Breakfast(), new Cereal());
        Recipe r2 = new Recipe(new Breakfast(), new Meat()); // compile time error
    }
}
```